# Kde global menu with PhpStorm or Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, phpstorm, kde-plasma, plasmoid

I have a problem with Kde Global Menu.

Debian buster

KDE 5.13.5:

KDE Framework: 5.49.0

Qt Version: 5.11.2

and PhpStorm 2018.3 EAP - Build #PS-183.4284.100

I'm using latte dock with global menu that for some programs works (for instance google chrome works with global menu) but don't for PhpStorm or visual studio code

Answer (score 4):

In fact, there is a whole thread regarding Global menu support is reported already on JetBrains YouTrack:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-169904

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue.
You need install appmenu-gtk-module package and use VSCodium instead VSCode there is not many differences but VSCodium works great with Global Menu.
You can download deb from http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/a/appmenu-gtk-module/appmenu-gtk3-module_0.7.6-2_amd64.deb